# Changing a heading in Woo Commerce file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The site is located at http://nancyhamiltonart.com/product/yellow-river/

Near the bottom, there's a "Related Products" text. I'm trying to change it to "Related Paintings".

I've narrowed down where I believe the string is, but when I updated and reload, it's not working.

Here's what I've changed (from **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php**)

```
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="related products">

    <h2><?php _e( 'Related Paintings', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

</div>
```

Line 3 -

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Related Paintings', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

is where I made the change, but nothing changed. Is there a different string that creates the output I'm referring to?

Thoughts one what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I added the following in the functions.php file...

```
//Changes text "Related Products" to "Related Paintings
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Related Products' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Related Paintings', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Everything seems to work now...

Comment: don't edit the plugin's file... it get's overwritten on plugin updates... make a folder in your theme folder, name it woocommerce, then create single-product folder... copy related.php there and do the edits...

Comment: @Reigel - Take a look at the update I made above. Are you saying, I can remove this from the functions.php file and following your instructions, this will still work?

Comment: ahh that will do too... and best approach... just don't edit plugins :)